# Given one set of 2D points as groud truth, how to match it with one observed set

Tags: charts, match, point-cloud-library

Assume set `A={P1, P2, P3,P4,p5}` is known.
The coordinate system of A is o1.  each point P is a 2d point which only have coordinates [x, y]. we can obtain the distance between each pair of points.

$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & d12 & d13 & d14 & d15 \
d21 & 0 & d23 & d24 & d25 \
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \
d51 & d52 & d53 & d54 & 0 \
\end{matrix}
$$

Now, we observe one set of points, B=[B1,B2,B3], and coordinate system is o2.

Unknown rotation(R) and transition(T) exist between coordinate system o1 and o2. But we know that all points B1-B3 are from A though observational error may exists. how to determine the correct matchings. e.g. B1(P2),B2(p3),B3(p5).

may be graph match can be used. but I can not find a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by using 2D ICP provided in PCL library. The result is correct.